# What precautions should i do to avoid being scammed for Bitcoins?

Tags: trade, fraud

I am a modest follower of Bitcoins and other Altcoins though recently i was scammed by few fake and fraudulent online buyers in a few days time when trading for Bitcoins.I never been scammed for any other currency ever so far over the internet and i am a very active online user but didn't have good experience with Bitcoins.All suggestions will be highly appreciated about how to escape from BTC scams Online as BTC is the X-Generation currency and i love it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always be alert and take the IP address and other social media details of the buyers before making any trade or exchange.Use middleman services and also trade with trusted buyers on regular basis.Never go first with new buyers.Many more.